# ImportError: No module named matplotlib with matplotlib installed

Tags: linux, matplotlib, python-3.4

**The code line:**

```
import matplotlib
```

**The error:**

> ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'

**The problem:**

```
which python3.4    % /usr/bin/python3.4
```

**Where is matplotlib installed?**

```
sudo find /usr | grep matplotlib  % /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/...
```

**Some considerations:**

- OS: Linux Mint 17.2
- I need to use Python 3.4

**Solutions:**

- `import sys sys.path.append('/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/')` (Not happy with this one).
- Using `pip3 install matplotlib` or `sudo pip3 install matplotlib` (Recieving errors, and i dont like this one too).
- Using `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` (May be the perfect one, but installs matplotlib in python2.7 directory).

How can i make matplotlib work for python3?
Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just when i was about to make the question realized that instead of typing

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

**I needed to type**

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

Comment: xD helped me thnx!

Comment: Thanks for giving a n00b answer as well as the proper answer.