# No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, python-3.5

Have found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771559/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-with-matplotlib-installed), however haven't found proper solution.

Here's a code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,2,5])
plt.show()
```

Run, got the message:

> ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package

I run Linux Mint 18 with preinstalled python-2.7 and python-3.5 (I use python3), before that I was installing modules with a simple `sudo apt-get install` method and that worked great.

Before running this the code above, I've installed matplotlib in a usual way `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`. As it haven't worked out, started to look for solution.

**Python location**

`which python3      /usr/bin/python3`

**Current Matplotlib installed**

`sudo find /usr | grep matplotlib    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib`

**My tries:**

1) I've removed matplotlib with `autoremove`, and tried to make it `sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib` instead. Didn't worked out.

2) Used: `pip3 install matplotlib` or `sudo pip3 install matplotlib`. Received errors like:

> command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build- ....

3) Then I found another solution:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3env
source py3env/bin/activate
pip install matplotlib
```

Same outcome.

Haven't tried to use `import sys sys.path.append('/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/')`(proposed in link above), but as I am not sure what exactly this command does (quite a newbie to python and programming itself) - haven't risked.

Comment: In your virtualenv, when you do `pip install matplotlib`, do you get an error, or does it install successfully? On Ubuntu 14.04 I was able to install and import using the your try #3 example with Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: Check if you have file name `matplotlib.py` in your current directory.

Comment: I think Mike Muller has it-- if you happened to name the script you are running "matplotlib" (as I just did), you will see this error.  Just rename your script to literally anything else, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 35):

If you are using pycharm and have matplotlib.py in your current working directory than you get this error. Just delete or rename the matplotlib.py file and it will work.

Comment: almost 5 years later it's still a thing...

Answer (score 5):

don't name any file as matplotlib.py within your working directory

Comment: Two [much](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46261207/354577) [older](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49111409/354577) (over a year) answers say the exact same thing. Please don't repeat answers.

Answer (score 4):

In your working directory, check if there is any file matplotlib.py
Delete that file and import matplotib again. That should work.

Comment: What does this add to [the answer from six months earlier saying the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46261207/354577)? Please don't repeat answers.

Answer (score 4):

simply install:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem reasons in my case were

1. python 3.8.2 with matplotlib that I downloaded was for 3.7. Make sure they are the same.
2. python 64 bits version with matplotlib 32bits. Make sure they are the same

   Use `python -m pip install package_which_you_need` to install packages for Windows
3. Make sure to add to PATH the environment variables I forgot to do in my case
4. pip version was old use
   Use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade pip to the latest for Windows
5. I saved the file name as matplotlib.py. Try to avoid that
6. Finally I typed `matplotlib.pyplot` as `matplotlib.plyplot` remember to check for typos first. The error message looks similar even though I corrected all the steps above.

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.plyplot'

Comment: For me, the reason was that I had saved the file as matplotlib.py and so the problem.
It was so obvious but just got overlooked.

Thanks !