# Show matplotlib plots in Ubuntu (Windows subsystem for Linux) - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, ubuntu-14.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have followed the answer in the question linked below to the letter, and it works beautifully in Python 2, but I need this to work with Python 3 also. I can't seem to get matplotlib to play nicely in Python 3.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)
```

And here is the output I get:

```
OMP: Error #100: Fatal system error detected.
OMP: System error #22: Invalid argument
[1]    5245 abort (core dumped)  python
```

[Show matplotlib plots in Ubuntu (Windows subsystem for Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397162/show-matplotlib-plots-in-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Comment: UPDATE: I think the issue lies within `IPython 6.4.0`. Plotting works in python shell, not IPython:
`In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
`In [2]: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-dhogue'`
`failed to get the current screen resources`
`QXcbConnection: XCB error: 170 (Unknown), sequence: 170, resource id: 90, `
`major code: 146 (Unknown), minor code: 20`
`[truncated]`
`In [5]: plt.plot(t, s)`
`OMP: Error #100: Fatal system error detected.`
`OMP: System error #22: Invalid argument`
`[1]    6933 abort (core dumped)  ipython`

Comment: good luck. I had similar issues one day, and that's why i switched from xming to vcXsrv.