# Recurring problem with plotting graphs in WSL Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, plot, xming

I am writing a code that should graph a simple function, and it temporarily works, but I keep encountering this cycle of problems when I restart my computer:

1. The first time I try running the code, it doesn't send out any errors, but neither does it create any graphs.

--> To solve this, I installed **Xming** and wrote the `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` command in bash, as suggested by *AwokeKnowing* in [Show matplotlib plots in Ubuntu (Windows subsystem for Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397162/show-matplotlib-plots-in-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux).

2. When I run the code, with the above adjustments, I get the following Error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable.
```

--> To solve this, I add the line of code:

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

as proposed by *Serenity* in [_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable)

3. After doing this, and running the code, initially graphs properly. But if I try again another day, it doesn't. The code runs normally, but no graph is displayed.

--> To make it work, I remove the line of code:

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

And by doing this, the code graphs again.

Then, when I restart my computer, the sequence of problems starts all over again.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I am very new with using Python, so it is very possible that I am missing something obvious.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
#Imports
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as ply
from dolfin import *
import numpy as np
from mshr import *
import math
from math import exp

plt.plot(tiemporeal,fcmM1)
plt.xlabel('Tiempo')
plt.ylabel('Resistencia')
plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot, and sorry for possible formatting mistakes.

PS. I am using Python3 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For legacy WSL it should suffice to add

```sh
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file - the default backend should then work properly. For WSL 2 it is more complicated, you need to get the name of the server from `/etc/resolv.conf` and then the mask from `ifconfig`. For example on my system:

```sh
wmiller@lcl:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file,
# add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.28.176.1
```

and

```sh
wmiller@lcl:~$ ifconfig | grep 'inet '
        inet 172.28.176.7  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.28.191.255 
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
```

So my `DISPLAY` needs to be `172.28.176.7:240.0`. This gets slightly complicated to extract automatically, but adding the following command to `~/.bashrc` works for me:

```sh
export DISPLAY=$((ifconfig | grep -f <(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver |
                  awk -F'[. ]' '{print $2"."$3}') | awk '{for(i=1; i <=NF; i++) 
                  {if($i == "inet") print $(i+1)}}' ; ifconfig | 
                  grep -f <(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | 
                  awk -F'[. ]' '{print $2"."$3}') | 
                  awk '{for(i=1; i <=NF; i++) {if($i == "netmask") print $(i+1)}}' | 
                  awk -F'.' '{print $3"."$4}') 
                 | tr "\n" " " | awk '{print $1":"$2}')
```

In either case you may also need to disable access control in your xserver client - I'm not sure about Xming but vcxsrv simply requires the commandline argument `-ac` or to check Disable Access Control during launch. You will also need to ensure that the windows firewall is permitting the connections. You may find [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4106) useful.

Also note that `'Agg'` is a non-gui backend, using it will not display figures. I find that with my setup `'TkAgg'` works best.

Comment: Changing the display environment to 'TkAgg' did the trick. Thanks!