# How to show matplotlib windows in WSL2 under Win11?

Tags: python, matplotlib, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

When I try to show a `matplotlib` window from Python 3 via `show()` I get the following error:

> UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.

So following various threads here on SO I tried the following:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
```

> Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running

I also tried it with `matplotlib.use("QtAgg")`, which leads to a similar error:

> Cannot load backend 'QtAgg' which requires the 'qt' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running

So it seems regardless of what backend I try, `matplotlib` thinks its in headless mode. However, I can run other X apps from that WSL installation under Win11 just fine, for example `xclock` or `sqlitebrowser`. They all work with the X server built into Win11. The `DISPLAY` env. variable is set to:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

Any ideas how I can get `matplotlib` windows working under Win11?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show matplotlib plots (and other GUI) in Ubuntu (WSL1 & WSL2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397162/show-matplotlib-plots-and-other-gui-in-ubuntu-wsl1-wsl2)

Comment: @Alex No, I tried that already. Instsalling `python-tk` does not help, and installing another X server does not seem to be the right solution, as Win11 comes with its own X server, which works fine with other X apps, as said.

Comment: That would've been good information to include in your original post, did you try reconfiguring the `DISPLAY` env variable to use `localhost:0.0` as suggested in the linked post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the records, if someone faces the same problem in WSL under Win11:

The `.show()` function of `matplotlib` was working fine when called directly from the console. It turned out that even though `:0` is valid as value, the `DISPLAY` variable was not set when I ran my program from VS Code. After setting that env. variable in the IDE's run configuration everything works fine.

Comment: Hi, do you have any info on configuring the display variable? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PavanInguva https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables

Comment: For anyone else with this error, I had the same issue but my display env was set correctly.

Turns out my python installation didn't have tkinter installed. I installed python 3.11 from pyenv and tkinter modules were not installed. This can be resolved with:

sudo apt-get install python3-tk tk-dev

and reinstalling python

Comment: Thanks for the help both! Redoing the Python installation (through conda) solved the problem for me as well as indicated by @ColinCheung above.