# Matplotlib function plt.show() doesn't open any window

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu

IDE : Neovim,
Terminal : Ubuntu

I'm using matplotlib to show some random graph but `plt.show()` doesn't open any window, here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

plt.plot(X, y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib does not show my drawings although I call pyplot.show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What if you run the script on command line: `python your_script.py`? I do not think it has something to do with neovim

Comment: so basically i tried to run it in pycharms terminal and it works but it didn't work on ubuntu terminal (btw i'm on windows)  so i think that its a problem with ubuntu but i don't know what

Comment: Then it is not related to neovim. I have removed the tag. I think it is related to DISPLAY env missing for WSL. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43397162/6064933