# Plot with matplotlib in WSL2

Tags: python, matplotlib, wsl-2

I have tried several post recommendations and follow several guides to use matplotlib in wsl2 in my windows machine. None of the tutorials worked. For instance, I have installed x11 apps follwing this tutorial:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

I have followed this post [Show matplotlib plots (and other GUI) in Ubuntu (WSL1 & WSL2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397162/show-matplotlib-plots-and-other-gui-in-ubuntu-wsl1-wsl2)

Now it get stuck when I try to run a plot(...)
[image]

I am working on a windows10 with wsl2, ubuntu distro machine.

the display is set to:

```
(.env) user@machine:~/project$ echo $DISPLAY
172.30.240.1:0
```

Could anyone help me to get this working?

Comment: I'm not able to help, but after reading that post I suspect that anyone who can will need more information, like are you on Windows 10 or 11? What's the output of `echo $DISPLAY`? They may want to see your `.bashrc`

Comment: I have addedd the information. Thanks for the point!

Comment: Never post textual data as picture, they are very poor format to exchange data, consume more bandwidth while preventing other people to copy paste it!

Comment: `plt.show()` seems to do the job out of the box on WSL2 Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use matplotlib in wsl2 then you don't need x11.

Dive into your link you listed will find [Diagnosing "cannot open display" type issues with WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/wiki/Diagnosing-%22cannot-open-display%22-type-issues-with-WSLg).

Run `export DISPLAY=:0` in your shell so the `plot()` can run normally.