executing python code in wsl (ubuntu) takes unreasonably too long time and gives warning that FigureCanvasAgg is not interactive
I have a simple python code, only 4 lines of code.
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,2,4])
plt.show()

I am using visual studio code with wsl2 (Ubuntu 22-04) terminal for execution.
I also use XLaunch for using the plt.show() function in wsl.
When I execute the code, it takes a long time, and finally it gives me the following warning:
 UserWarning: FigureCanvasAgg is non-interactive, and thus cannot be shown
  plt.show()

I have configured before the XLaunch and vscode via this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397162/show-matplotlib-plots-and-other-gui-in-ubuntu-wsl1-wsl2and it was working nice, but now I don't know what have changed and why the execution is talking too long time.
thanks in advance.
what I did is to add this line matplotlib.use('qt5agg') but it didn't solve it.

Could you give us an estimate about how long "unreasonably too long" is? I'm curious to know how long this takes to run. Also do you know which lines are taking so long? sometimes matplotlib can be slow to import, or maybe the plt.show() is being slow? All of these things can only be tested by you since this seems to be unique to your machines context.

did you try to run it without visual studio code and without wsl? Maybe you should run it directly in Windows.

it takes about 2 minutes. like when I write python mycode.py in terminal. it takes two minute and finally print this warning message.
before I remember for such a code, it takes a few seconds (5 seconds maximum) to run the code and plot me something.

I thinkk @furas is right. because I always struggle with running python in wsl, especially when I want to plot something, I did a lot of work to be able to see the plot via the XLaunch, only because I like to use linux and learn how to use linux, but it takes to much time.
