# ImportError: No module named matplotlib even using pip install matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I am importing matplotlib from Jupyter Notebook but get the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

Settings:

Python 2
MacBook
conda:    4.3.30

After run

```
conda list
```

it got:

ipykernel   4.6.1
ipython     5.3.0
matplotlib  2.0.2   np112py36_0
matplotlib  2.1.1

Some commends I tried but failed

1.

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

and shows

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

2.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

and shows

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

commends 1 and 2 are from this site

[ImportError: No module named matplotlib with matplotlib installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771559/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-with-matplotlib-installed)

3.

```
pip install matplotlib
```

and shows

Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.0 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)

commend 3 from this website

[ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176591/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-pyplot)

Update:

run this

```
pip2 install matplotlib
```

it was successfully installed like this

Collecting matplotlib
Downloading matplotlib-2.1.1-cp27-cp27m...
...
Successfully built subprocess32
Installing collected packages: subprocess32, six, python-dateutil, backports.functools-lru-cache, pyparsing, cycler, numpy, pytz, matplotlib
Successfully installed backports.functools-lru-cache-1.4 cycler-0.10.0 matplotlib-2.1.1 numpy-1.13.3 pyparsing-2.2.0 python-dateutil-2.6.1 pytz-2017.3 six-1.11.0 subprocess32-3.2.7

then restart Anaconda and Jupyter, and it was not imported.

Comment: what are the outputs of `which python` and `which pip`?

Comment: Hi @PaulH  I run "pip install matplotlib" on python 3 (it was not necessary though);  and "pip2 install matplotlib" on python 2.  Restart and it was not imported.

Comment: doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you already have matplot lib installed for python3.6, just run with `python3.6` instead of `python`, which ends up running python2.

pip will also normally install packages for python2 so if you want to install them for python3 use `pip3 install <package>`

since `apt-get` can not be found you are probably running CentOS which uses `yum` instead as the default package manager. To install you'd normally use the following command:

```
yum install <packagename>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! My objective is to install matplotlib for python 2 on Jupyter. So I use pip2 install matplotlib, and the terminal shows Requirement already satisfied, but Jupyter could not import it somehow. Plus, the matplotlib works in text editor.    P.S. Yum command not found.

Comment: If your aim is to use python 2 then you need matplotlib installed for python2 and you also need to `pip install jupyter` so that it uses python2 and possibly uninstall it with `pip3` if you installed it there to avoid other  possible conflicts. Then try running jupyter and using matplotlib

Comment: @mental , please have a look at this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789254/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mplfinance-errors-out-even-after-pip-st